# Enable Ship Button Based on Order Status

Tags: magento2, shipping, order-status

When a customer placed an order , We will place order in processing state. After that QC team will pack the order when the QC is completed then they will change the order status to QC Passed .

Now i want to show "SHIP" button on QC Passed state only. For remaining order status it won't be show. How can i implement this?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context">
        <plugin name="remove_button_from_sales_veiw" type="SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Widget\Context" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Plugin/Widget/Context.php

```
<?php

namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Widget;

use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class Context
{
    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    private $registry;

    /**
     * Context constructor.
     *
     * @param Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $subject
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\ButtonList $buttonList
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterGetButtonList(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $subject,
        $buttonList
    ) {
        if ($subject->getRequest()->getFullActionName() == 'sales_order_view') {
            if ($this->getOrder() && ($this->getOrder()->getStatus() == 'pending')) {
                $buttonList->remove('order_ship');
            }
        }

        return $buttonList;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve order model object
     *
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
     */
    private function getOrder()
    {
        return $this->registry->registry('sales_order');
    }
}
```

Replace following condition to your condition :

> if ($this->getOrder() && ($this->getOrder()->getStatus() ==
>   'pending')) {

Comment: Hi Sohel , Thanks for your answer and it worked like charm. Now i want to create a new order state called as "qc_processed" and assigned to "processing" status but when i called $this->getOrder()->getStatus() still showing "processing" status instead of qc_processed state. Can i know how can i get this?